# Dropdown boxes in MVC 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to implement editing addresses in my view.

An address has basic strings for street, town etc. It also has a country id. I have a table in my database of countries.

In my controller I create a SelectList for these countries:

```
ViewBag.Countries = _countryRepo.GetAll().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id });
```

Now in my view I want to be able to use this select list to allow users to select the country.

I originally thought:

```
@Html.DropDownList("countryId", (IEnumerable<Country>)ViewBag.Countries, "Select")
```

I have two addresses:

```
public class Company() 
{
    public Address HeadOffice { get; set; }
    public Address SecondOffice { get; set; }
}
```

So when displaying the view I need to have the select country shown. I don't think I can do this in my controller because if I select one like this:

```
 ViewBag.Countries = _countryRepo.GetAll().Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id, Selected = c.Id == model.HeadOffice.Id ? true : false });
```

This will only work for the HeadOffice.

From what I can there are two options. Have two different select lists or manually build the select list in the view:

```
<select name="HeadOffice.CountryId">
    @foreach(var c in (IEnumerable<Country>)ViewBag.Countries)
    {
         <option value="@c.Id" @(c.Id == Model.HeadOffice.Id ? "selected='true'" : "">@c.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

What is the best way? Both seem wrong and not nice. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a ViewModel that takes in the list of countries once then expose 2 different lists. This way you only query the database ones but still keep you View clean

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
  public Address HeadOffice { get; set; }
  public Address SecondOffice { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get;set;}

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> HeadOfficeCountries
  {
     get 
     {
       return GetCountriesList(Countries, HeadOffice.Id);
     }
  }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SecondOfficeCountries
  {
     get 
     {
       return GetCountriesList(Countries, SecondOffice.Id);
     }
  }

  private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCountriesList(IEnumerable<Country> countries, int forAddress)
  {
     return countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.Id, Selected = c.Id == forAddress ? true : false });
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Great idea - I will do just this. Thanks.

Comment: @BassamMehanni you are writing the same code here twice. One of the principals of ASP.NET MVC is to follow the DRY approach.

Comment: @tugberk ps DRY is not an MVC specific principle, but great point none the less

Comment: @BassamMehanni I know that it is not but ASP.NET MVC Framework has the notion of conventions and the ASP.NET MVC team is try to force this approach. IMO, we should follow the DRY approach on every phase of our lives.

Comment: @BassamMehanni BTW, just pass the id there as parameter as I do below. That would be enough I think.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following blog post:

[A Way of Working with Html Select Element (AKA DropDownList) In ASP.NET MVC](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-code-review-sharp2-a-way-of-working-with-html-select-element-aka-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc)

You will find all the details inside the blog post.

**Edit:**

For your case, the below code should work fine:

```
public ActionResult Index() { 

    ViewBag.DLForHeadOffice = GetItems(model.HeadOffice.Id);
    ViewBag.DLForSecondOffice = GetItems(model.SecondOffice.Id);

    //continue your code
}


private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetItems(int id) {

    _countryRepo.GetAll().
        Select(c => 
            new SelectListItem { 
                Text = c.Name, 
                Value = c.Id, 
                Selected = c.Id == id ? true : false 
            }
        );       
}
```

Comment: The blog post link is missing although I don't think that was intended.

Comment: @FrazellThomas now it is there.

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to use the drop down list. My question was the best way to get it to work for two different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using HTML Helpers?

I have some private static Dictionary variables in our class that deal with caching of the dictionary so we don't have to fetch a list of countries (thats what countryDictionary is below) each time the dropdown is rendered.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CountrySelectFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string emptyText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        SelectListItem[] SingleEmptyItem = new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = emptyText != null ? emptyText : "", Value = "" } };
        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, emptyText != null ? SingleEmptyItem.Concat(new SelectList(countryDictionary, "Key", "Value")) : new SelectList(countryDictionary, "Key", "Value"), htmlAttributes);
    }
```

From here, after you register the namespace you put your HTML Helper in, you can use:

```
 <%: Html.CountrySelectFor(model => Model.HeadOffice.CountryId) %>
```

Just for your reference, here is out snippet for the countryList. The "Caching" lines below won't exist for you, those are some custom classes we made for managing application cache.

```
 private static Dictionary<int, string> countryList
    {
        get
        {
            IList<Models.Country> countries = Caching.HTTPCache.Get(Caching.Common.CountryCacheName) as IList<Models.Country>;

            if (countries == null)
            {
                countries = Models.Country.Get(); //Loads all countries from the DB
                Caching.HTTPCache.Add(Caching.Common.CountryCacheName, countries , new TimeSpan(0, 0, Caching.Common.CountryCacheDuration, 0, 0)); //Adds the results to the cache
            }

            return countries .ToDictionary(t => t.CountryId, t => t.CountryName);
        }
    }
```